# Natural Languages

Tags: regular-languages, natural-language-processing

Can one imply that natural languages can be described by regular grammar? Is that what happens through NPL? Trying to understand the subject of how spoken language can be converted to data and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this paper](http://people.umass.edu/%7Epartee/726_04/lectures/Lecture%2013%20revised%20Are%20NLs%20Finite-state.pdf) for an extended discussion which includes the old Chomskyan center-embedding arguments that English, for example, is not regular.
See [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53165/proving-that-english-is-not-a-regular-language) for an argument that natural languages are not context-free and therefore not regular. Moreover, there is [no agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) as to what a syntactic theory of natural languages would look like. The situation for semantic theories of language is [even worse](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning/). So we have a long way to go.